# Wifi signal logger device

Tags: hardware, wifi

I am working on indoor gps tracking and for this I need a wifi signal logger which can receive the signals from different smartphone(whose wifi is turned on) an send it to a remote server. I wanted to know, where I can get this kind of hardware, having capability to receive signals from different smartphones and log its signal strength and mac address in a remote server.

Please let me know the details.

Thank you in advance.

Pravin Prasad

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, Wifi clients(smartphones, notebooks etc.) send periodic `Probe Request` packets to actively seek wifi access points and Wifi APs(routers, gateways etc.) send periodic `Beacon` packets to advertise the presence of WLAN network.

You can use any wifi capable device like a smartphone or notebook to log the above packets.

1. Configure your wireless card in monitor mode.
2. Use a packet sniffer(for example, [wireshark](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)) to capture the traffic on the wireless interface or write your own with [libpcap](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap). You may filter on the packet type, source, destination etc.